# Wait for backend thread to finish after application.run in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, gtk

I want to wait for a backend thread ([Like this](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples/blob/master/src/bin/communication_thread.rs) but in my case the backend manages a database which I want to close properly before the application actually exits) to finish (e.g. join it) after `application.run()` has finished.

- [My actual non working main.rs](https://gitlab.com/kuenstler/yayi-rs/-/blob/6fa9423e8ed27c7cfb232b26ed8b0af31344f691/src/main.rs) (the closure needs to be non-`mut`)
- [the thread to wait for](https://gitlab.com/kuenstler/yayi-rs/-/blob/6fa9423e8ed27c7cfb232b26ed8b0af31344f691/src/lib.rs#L138)

```rust
use gio::prelude::*;
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{ApplicationWindow, Label};
use std::env::args;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let application = gtk::Application::new(
        Some("com.github.gtk-rs.examples.communication_thread"),
        Default::default(),
    )
    .expect("Initialization failed...");

    let (thr, mut receiver) = start_communication_thread();

    application.connect_activate(move |application| {
        build_ui(application, receiver.take().unwrap())
    });
    application.run(&args().collect::<Vec<_>>());
    thr.join();
}

fn build_ui(application: &gtk::Application, receiver: glib::Receiver<String>) {
    let window = ApplicationWindow::new(application);
    let label = Label::new(None);
    window.add(&label);

    spawn_local_handler(label, receiver);
    window.show_all();
}

/// Spawn channel receive task on the main event loop.
fn spawn_local_handler(label: gtk::Label, receiver: glib::Receiver<String>) {
    receiver.attach(None, move |item| {
        label.set_text(&item);
        glib::Continue(true)
    });
}

/// Spawn separate thread to handle communication.
fn start_communication_thread() -> (thread::JoinHandle<()>, Option<glib::Receiver<String>>) {
    let (sender, receiver) = glib::MainContext::channel(glib::PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    let thr = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut counter = 0;
        loop {
            let data = format!("Counter = {}!", counter);
            println!("Thread received data: {}", data);
            if sender.send(data).is_err() {
                break
            }
            counter += 1;
            thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        }
    });
    (thr, Some(receiver))
}
```

As mentioned above, the only error remaining is that `application.connect_activate()` takes an `Fn` closure, the current implementation is `FnMut`.

Comment: Links to external sites are fine, but to make questions useful for the future, please include your [mre] in the question itself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `receiver` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:17:31
   |
17 |         build_ui(application, receiver.take().unwrap())
   |                               ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

So you cannot use "receiver" mutably, which is necessary for you to `take()` its contents.

But if you wrap the receiver inside a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), then you can access the immutable `Cell`'s contents mutably. So add this line directly after the line with `start_communication_thread()`:

```rust
    let receiver = Cell::new(receiver);
```

There might be some more correct answer as I am only a beginner at Rust, but at least it seems to work.

Please note that this changes the `take()` call to be called against the `Cell` instead of `Option`, whose implementation has the same effect, replacing the `Cell`'s contents with `None`.

Comment: *it seems to work* — why aren't yous **sure** that it works? Perhaps that means that the OP did not provide a [MRE]? Hopefully you aren't wasting your time tryig to answer a poorly-specified question.

Comment: No time wasted, since I learned a lot myself here. I am not fully aware of the differencies between `Fn` and `FnMut` and why the api would choose to use `Fn` and thus block mutable use of the captured variables. It is possible that the api also accidentally was being unnecessarily restrictive and could have used `FnMut` as well. I cannot tell. So I am not sure if my answer is correct.